# fgets function is completely ignored

Tags: c, input, io, newline, fgets

Here is an example of the problem I face:

```
void print() {
    printf("Hello");
}

int main() {
    char a[LENGTH]; //LENGTH equals 20
    printf("Please enter something: ");
    fgets(a, LENGTH, stdin);
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

The program shows 'Please enter something: ' on the screen and doesn't let the user enter the string using the fgets() function. It moves directly to the print() function, therefore printing 'Hello' on the screen.

Why does this happen? Is there any way to fix it?

**EDIT**:

The same problem happens with this code, too:

```
void prints(){
    printf("Hello world, how are you?");
}

int main() {
    printf("blah\n");
    printf("blah\n");
    printf("blah\n");
    printf("blah\n");
    printf("blah\n");
    printf("blah\n");//all these printfs are necessary.
    printf("Enter a number: ");

    fflush(stdout);
    fflush(stdin);
    int number;
    scanf(" %d", &number);
    printf("Please write something: \n");

    char a[MAXSTRING];
    fgets(a, MAXSTRING, stdin);
    prints();

}
```

Comment: How do you run your program?

Comment: The `scanf()` is your problem, here, leaving a newline in the input stream, which `fgets()` then consumes and immediately returns. Nothing to do with `printf()`. Don't mix `scanf()` with `fgets()`. About a million duplicates of this question. And `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I completely agree, but this does not explain the problem with the first program.

Comment: @jdarthenay: The first program is fake code, not his real code. See his first comment to the only current answer: "I thought that if I just write a very simple program like the above, it would be equal to the piece of code I have a problem with."

Comment: Yes, the second one is more close to my real code. 

gsamara's answer is 100% correct for the first program.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the updated question; change this:

```
scanf(" %d", &number);
printf("Please write something: \n");
```

to this:

```
scanf(" %d", &number);
getchar();
printf("Please write something: \n");
```

The issue is relatie to the [Caution with scanf()](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/caution-when-reading-char-with-scanf-c/) example we talked over before. The user inputs a number and he does what? He hits enters!

`scanf()` does not consume that (you told it to read a number, with `%d`), thus a newline (which came up from the enter stroke) is kept in the input buffer. You then call `fgets()` and finds something in the input buffer, so it acts on it.

A simple solution would be to use [getchar()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/), to consume the newline, `scanf()` didn't collect, so that the input buffer is empty, when `fgets()` is called.

---

Change this:

```
printf("Please enter something: ");
```

to this:

```
printf("Please enter something: \n");
```

to consume the newline!

---

Read the [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) please:

> Reads characters from stream and stores them as a C string into str until (num-1) characters have been read or either a newline or the end-of-file is reached, whichever happens first.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work to my own program. I thought that if I just write a very simple program like the above, it would be equal to the piece of code I have a problem with. 

Does it matter that there are a lot of printf() functions before? 

Thanks anyway. (Ευχαριστώ, πάντως :) )

Comment: @George, μπράβο for the attempt to create a minimal example. Do you have a link with the whole (minimal again) code?

Comment: A (website) link? No.

Comment: Anything that could lead me to the code. For example, if I had a question for my quicksort, I would provide that link: https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/quicksort-c/ . Maybe try to enhance your minimal example? :) To be honest, I wasn't able to reproduce the reported behavior, @George.

Comment: No, sorry, because it is a project I have to do for my course in C programming. 

Anyway, I will use the classic scanf() function. 

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Tried that before. Doesn't work. It is like the program completely jumps the fgets() line, strange, isn't it? However, when I remove the print() function call, the program can call the fgets() function.

Comment: @George I am not able to tell without seeing the actual code. These issue typically arise when there is something left in the input buffer and `fgets()` consumes that instantly. Something like this for example: https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/caution-when-reading-char-with-scanf-c/ . Did you try `fflush(stdin)` too?

Comment: Yes, I tried fflush(stdin) too, but without any success. I posted an edited question above.

Comment: @George, I found the solution! As I had said, input buffer had some leftovers. ;)

Comment: The solution in current answer also has problems. User could hit "42<space><return>" and your single `getchar()` will consume only the <space>.

Comment: Yes, at least loop until you find the newline, or even better, avoid `scanf()` altogether, and replace it with `fgets()` followed by `strtol()` or at a minimum `sscanf()`. Mixing line-oriented and non-line-oriented input like this and hacking around the problems by searching for newlines is barking.

Comment: The solution answers the question @jdarthenay. What you say, *of course* makes sense, but that's another story. Moreover, I wouldn't like to put a guy that has just started to get the point to look that into. ;)